# How to create a new path that contains the same path as the source but with a different root?

Tags: c#, file, random, copy

I'm about to develop a software in C# that must select random folders (in a scenario with 10.000 folders more or less) that follow these rules:

1. select only the ones which contains files;
2. the software must stop the selection when the size of selected folder is 8GB;
3. when I copy a single folder, I need to keep the whole path of that folder (if c:\folder\temp\hello is the copied one, I want to keep d:\COPIED\folder\temp\hello);

I think I will do somethings like:

1. analyze the whole list of folder starting from an assigned root;
2. select random "line" in this list, moving it to the "selected list", counting the size;
3. when I reach 8GB, I stop this first phase, and I start to copy it;

I think here it is not a big trouble. What do you think about? Any suggestions?

My real problem will to "recreate" the whole path for each single folder when I move it.
How can I do it? Create folder for each level with C# API or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the last paragraph is the question? I understand it in the following way:

> How to create a new path that contains the same path as the source but
>   with a different root?

Then you can use the [`Path` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) and it's static methods + `String.Substring` to get the new path.

`D:\Copied` is your root destination folder which you use in `Path.Combine`. Then you have to add the old-path without it's root-folder(there is no method in `Path` for this, i'll use `Substring`):

```
var rootDest = @"D:\Copy";                                  // your root directory
var pathSource = @"C:\Test\Test.txt";                       // a sample file
var root = Path.GetPathRoot(pathSource);                    // C:\
var oldPathWithoutRoot = pathSource.Substring(root.Length); // Test\Test.txt
var newPath = Path.Combine(rootDest, oldPathWithoutRoot);   // D:\Copy\Test\Test.txt
```

Then use [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx) to copy all files in the folder from the old to the new path.

You have to check if the directory exists and create it otherwise:

```
var targetDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(newPath);
if (!Directory.Exists(targetDir))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir);                   // D:\Copy\Test
}
File.Copy(pathSource, newPath);
```

Comment: Well, but what about this folder doesnt exist (D:\Copy\Test\)?

Comment: I'll try and let you know ;)

Comment: It works perfect! Thank you! Bizzare that -3, is it so stupid?

Comment: @markzzz: I have upvoted it, however, the question is not really clear(what have you tried, what was the core problem). Always ask clear, single questions on SO. If you want suggestions [`programmers`](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) is more appropriate.

Comment: But is there a Directory.Copy? Or I need to browse each file, for each directory, and do File.Copy?

Comment: @markzzz: There is no `Directory.Copy`, you have to loop all files in a directory and use the code above. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914.aspx On this way you are also able to catch exceptions where they happen and log on file level.